# What am I doing wrong with this input type=date default value? Template Driven Form Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-template

I am trying to give the date picker a default value, but nothing I tried has worked. What am I missing? Here's my html

```
    <input [(ngModel)]="model.birthday" type = "date" id = "birthday" name = "birthday" value="{{today | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'}} " #birthday = "ngModel">
```

ts

```
today = new Date();
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    
    
    let date = new Date();
    let day = date.getDate();
    let month = date.getMonth();
    let year = date.getFullYear();
    
    if (month < 10) month = parseInt("0" + month);
    if (day < 10) day = parseInt("0" + day);
    
    this.today = new Date(month + '/' + day + '/' + year);
```

Comment: Don't mix setting the `value` attribute with `[(ngModel)]`. You should probably be using `ngOnChanges` along with `firstChange` to set the default date if necessary directly against `model.birthday`.

Comment: Could you show me what you mean? How should I use firstChange and model.birthday? My first thought was use firstChange in an if and then I guess set something to this.today. I don't know if I'm on the right track.